# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')

Tags: reactjs

my screen

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { CART_ADD_ITEM } from '../constants/cartConstants'

export const addToCart = (id,qty) => async(dispatch,getState) => {
    const {data} = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/${id}`)

    dispatch({
        type:CART_ADD_ITEM,
        payload: {
            product:data._id,
            name:data.name,
            image:data.image,
            price:data.price,
            countInStock: data.countinStock,
            qty
        }
    })
    localStorage.setItem('cartItems',JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
}
```

my reducer

```
import { startTransition } from 'react'
import { CART_ADD_ITEM } from '../constants/cartConstants'

export const cartReducer = (state = {cartItems:[]},action)=> {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CART_ADD_ITEM:
            const item = action.payload
            const existItem = state.cartItems.find(x => x.product === item.product)
            if(existItem){
                return{...state, 
                cartItems: state.cartItems.map(x =>
                    x.product === existItem.product ? item: x)}
            }else{
                return{
                    ...state,
                    cartItems:[...state.cartItems,item]
                }
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Action

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { CART_ADD_ITEM } from '../constants/cartConstants'

export const addToCart = (id,qty) => async(dispatch,getState) => {
    const {data} = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/${id}`)

    dispatch({
        type:CART_ADD_ITEM,
        payload: {
            product:data._id,
            name:data.name,
            image:data.image,
            price:data.price,
            countInStock: data.countinStock,
            qty
        }
    })
    localStorage.setItem('cartItems',JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
}
```

Error when i'm trying to put something in a cart
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')
at cartReducer (cartReducers.js:8:1)
Probably it is because of null product, but how it becames null i don't know

Comment: Sorry about my other answer, had another look, and it was clear I misunderstood.
The problem is ultimate because at some point in the lifetime of your application `state.cartItems` becomes undefined and that's why it cant call `find`, but your answer looks fine on the face of it. Is it possible something else somewhere also operates on `state.cart`? Do you have any storage solution plugged into redux? E.g. localstorage?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. How are you using `cartReducer`?